# Protocol Headers across a network?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, protocols

Question from my review I *think* I have correct.

When a packet is routed across a network, the protocol headers are modified as the packet is passed between intermediate nodes (e.g. routers). Why?

From what I can tell, the NAT (network address translation tool) modifies the source and destination header fields to reflect the new source (that router) and the new destination (if there is one). Is this correct?

Comment: Not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]. You may get help on [su]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes that's right, the packet is encapsulated in **link layer packet** contains MAC address of the current router as Source and MAC address of the following router as destination on this route but the **application layer packet** doesn't change it's still containing the main source address and the final destination address.